# Image average multipe frame same matrix. Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signals, average, frames

I've a matrix RF = RF(512,1728). This matrix contain 9 images and the number of frame is equal 9, the first image considering one single frame is: RF1 = RF1(:,1:192) etc. So I'd like to average the hole matrix in order to obtain one single image.  any idea?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reshape the matrix

```
allRF=reshape(RF,[512,192,9]);
```

and compute the mean

```
meanRF=mean(allRF,3);
```

Comment: sorry, when I posted my answer I just saw that yours used a different method than the reshape thing, and I didn't refresh the page before I posted mine, so I didn't see you had made an edit. Now I look like a douche.

Comment: @Ash nah, dont worry! this happens a lot

Answer (score 1):

A simple, vectorized way:

```
k=reshape(RF,512,192,1728/192);
mean(k,3)
```